# User feedback for RESTful request in Power Bi

Tags: rest, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need to find a way to get access to a user-selected row or rather to any table that is already in "Power" Bi.

For testing to get some user feedback, I created a table Parameter clicking Modelling->New Parameter (wondering there are only numbers possible) with range 0 to 1. Now I tried to access the measurement 'Parameters'[Parameter Value] in Power Query.

Did not work, neither I found any Function for getting any kind of user-selected stuff.

So I need anything to replace the question marks to do my RESTful request.
Is there at least any way?

```
let
    userSelectedTableRow = ????,
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://url-for-get-request-with-rest/"& userSelectedTableRow[id])),
    ...
```

I don't want to do it with Enter Parameter windows, because there is no possibility to prevent illegal arguments (or is there?).

So in the end the user should select some row in the table, press refresh and the data is downloaded in dependence of the selected row. (just a simple thing you can build with e.g. R Shiny in like 5 minutes with no necessity of a frigging refresh button).

I'm glad about any hint could at least have anything to do with my problem.